# Dockerized Java Spring Boot application throws 504 Bad Gateway while its starting the application

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot

I have a java spring boot application deployed on a docker data center. Whenever we deploy stack for the service, as expected it kills existing containers and spins up new containers with new image. But the problem is we get 504 Bad Gateway while spring application starts inside the container which is typically 30-40 seconds. My hunch is since the container is up and running, load balancer sends requests to the container but the app is still starting, is there a way to get around this? It impacts because we have 5 containers for service and same thing happens for each containers. So good portion of users will get errors while this is happening.

Comment: My gut reaction is "deploy at midnight when no one will care..." As for a real solution, I would think about setting up your docker image with an apache web server in front of your spring application, set up in such a way that the apache web server replies with a friendly "booting up" page until the spring app is up, then delegates to it...

Comment: can you give us the docker container log and the command you use to run the docker image

Comment: You need somekind of Docker orchestrator (Kubernetes, Openshift, Swarm...) That will handle the creation/destruction of containers for you and avoid problems such as this one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution in your compose file for it: [`update_config`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#update_config)

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  your-app:
    image: your/image:old
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
        delay: <yourStartupTimeInSeconds+3>s
        order: stop-first
```

So when you deploy an updated version of `your/image`, swarm will shut down two containers, deploy two new ones, waits for `<yourStartupTimeInSeconds+3>` in seconds until it deploys 2 other replicas with the new image, waits again and the deploys the remaining one.

Your loadbalancer (service) in front of those does a health check anyway (a node may fail), right?

Comment: If you use an orchestrator, the heath check on the front-end load balancer will only check for your 'service' not container. so usually a simple TCP healthcheck at this level is sufficient. Here you set a simple delay... Why not set 1hour because I really need to be sure it is up? what happens when your process start to go wrong? you stuck with one wrong container. Put a heath check at container level, a HTTP heathcheck not TCP one, and test that response time is not timeout + the response is ok not ko. It also get your container in the service pool the safer and faster way

Comment: @wargre a) I give a damn about the individual container. For example, I have HAProxy or Varnish do backend checks. A Backend not reachable (for whatever reason)? Fine, use the remaining ones, and let swarm (in this example) do its work. b) An hour? Great, so I have two versions of my application out and about. Hardly desired. c) What happens if my start goes wrong? I beat the shit of of the guy who did a staging test. So what does an orchestration health check give us here? No answer, as with a wrong start. with the rolling update, if those containers fail, we will at least have 3 remaining.

Comment: Let say you have a HAProxy then your swarm cluster with your application scaled at 5 on 3 nodes.    It means HAProxy will just check is connection to the nodes are ok (TCP mode) or (in HTTP mode) you will connect to one node then request one random container of the service pool.  So yes it is stupid to want HTTP test backend through a 'service'.   Now  With your delay, you absolutly don't care about final status of your backend.  yes you can put something that "start" and return 404 on every request it will end in your pool Great job guy!!!!

Comment: Concept of orchestration with heath check / readyness probe / liveness probe are always the same!  start then test and if it is not good stop what you are doing and ask for a fix.   When at runtime something fail, just drop the container and restart another automatically.   NOTE: I'm also pissed because I fired somebody 2 week back because he disable a health check that put everything green on our dashboard.... Let say ... it wasn't true..

Comment: @wargre Well, now we have a state with orchestration checks. Does this enhance availability? No. When the first update round fails, the remaining ones are kept in place, your application level proxy takes note of the remaining ones, and you can fix the problems while still reachable. Good enough for me. And btw, no need to get personal.

Answer (score -1):

Every docker orchestrator have a 'health check' system that is designed to remove this issue (health check or readiness or liveness or ...).

If you create a 'ping' endpoint on your application (or something like that like a ready endpoint that also check needed resource), you can set the health check to make a HTTP request to this endpoint, and only be successful if you have response 200.

The starting container will only be on the service pool when the heath check will be ok. You container will not get any request until then.

Also, this kind of check is also use to decide if your container (pod in k8s) need to be restarted if there is an issue (application not dead, but in bad shapes that make response time really higher, or send error).

Note that some front-end load balancer can also use this kind of health check. But it need to be used only if you have a direct connection from this load balancer to docker containers  (not really a good practice this direct link).

Comment: This issue is not magically removed. The only thing that will happen that unless the health check fails, the container will not respond at all.

Comment: There is 5 containers. When one start, the health check will make this container out of the orchestration / loadbalacing which means no error.  Everybody do that everywhere

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: I also use healthchecks. Eg für my Databases. In Spring applications, services check ech other for availablility during boot. The problem is, that docker enables the ports meanwhile the app is not already running. What you can to is ping eg. mysqladmin in a mysql container because mysql admin is ready after the db is ready. For a bad gateway you can catch the exception and handle the error with a user notification. It really depends on you usecase.